# is it possible to only give certain folders' access to app?

Tags: box-api

I read the OAuth documentation on Box's website, and understood the steps to give resource access to application.

However, it looks like all resources (all folders and files) under box account will be exposed to authorized application. Is it possible to only give certain folders' access to application instead of all of them?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We're in the process of building out additional scopes but currently the only one available is full account read/write.

Comment: Nine months later - has the process of "building out additional scopes" been completed yet?